# How to read parameters from script in Jade / Pug?

Tags: javascript, pug, inline

I use express js and Jade as template engine.
I want to print parameters in jade file.

in a jade file:

```
script.
    var firstName = 'foo';
div
    p First name is #{firstName}
```

But it doesn't show the first name ... what is wrong with this?

Comment: You're mixing up client-side and server-side javascript. The content in you script tag is client-side javascript. The string interpolation you have with `#{firstName}` is something which will be rendered/parsed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a javascript variable in end-users' browsers when they load your webpage. Pug on the server has no access to it.

```
script.
  var firstName = 'foo';
```

To create a variable that Pug does have access to, do the following:

```
- var firstName = 'foo';
```

So to create a variable and then interpolate it into text when Pug compiles, you can do:

```
- var firstName = 'foo';
div
  p First name is #{firstName}
```